# FOSUserBundle связь с другой сущностью

Tags: symfony2, sonata, fosuserbundle

```
  /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="news_user",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="news_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
private $user;
```

сущность AppBundle:News , в админSonata появляется связь но при добавлении выскакивает [image: введите сюда описание изображения] адрес сущности верный, при указании требуемой сущности(которая в exception), пишит что нельзя найти такую сущность, как быть?

Comment: doctrine сформировала setter и getter для  user c неправильным адресом

Answer (score 0):

doctrine сформировала setter и getter для user c неправильным адресом